# Issue creating decorator in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

Can anyone let me know what mistake i'm making.

## Decorator

```
import time

def f1(f):

    a = time.time()
    f()
    b = time.time()
    c = b-a
    print("time required is", c)
@f1

def f3(f2):
    
    n = []
    for i in range(1000):
        n.append(i)
    print(sum(n), "for F3")
    f2()

@f3

def f4():

    n = []
    for i in range(1000):
       n.append(i)
    print(sum(n), "for F4")

f4
```

o/p:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/test.py", line 13, in <module>

@f1

File "C:/test.py", line 7, in f1

f()

TypeError: f3() missing 1 required positional argument: 'f2'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

looking to achieve something like this:

def decorator_with_args(decorator_to_enhance):

```
def decorator_maker(*args, **kwargs):

    def decorator_wrapper(func):

        return decorator_to_enhance(func, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorator_wrapper

return decorator_maker
```

@decorator_with_args

def decorated_decorator(func, *args, **kwargs):

```
def wrapper(function_arg1, function_arg2):

    print("Decorated with {0} {1}".format(args, kwargs))

    return func(function_arg1, function_arg2)

return wrapper
```

@decorated_decorator(42, 404, 1024)

def decorated_function(function_arg1, function_arg2):

```
print("Hello {0} {1}".format(function_arg1, function_arg2))
```

decorated_function("Universe and", "everything")

Comment: A decorator has to return a callable (like a function).

Comment: It is totally unclear to me what you expect this code to do. Without a clear statement of your intent, it is impossible to say what "mistake" you are making. You could, for example, be intending to create some code that throws an error. I don't know.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga basically what im trying to do is calculate the time difference in running function f3 and f4
So i want fn f1 to note the time before and after running fn f3 and f4 and give me the difference in time.
In this example, how do i call a fn using a decorator and which in turns calls another function using a decorator.
I hope i'm making sense, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: This doesn't make very much sense. Decorators *return functions*, they aren't used to call them. It sounds like you just want normal functions. Note, all your decorators return `None`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga basically i was looking for making a chain of decorators (parsing one decorator into another)
I looked at couple of examples but didn't understood much about it.

Comment: `@f1 def f3(f2): ...` is more or less equivalent to `def f3(f2): ... ; f3=f1(f3)`, try making your code work with the latter syntax to help you figure out what `f1` needs to be doing.

Comment: i have edited the post of what im trying to achieve but without trying to parse any argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can wrap and function in another *single* function that does not return any callable object, bear in mind that the wrapped function is no longer callable. Thus, when timing objects that do not require reusability of the original object, then your current code works:

```
import time
def timeit(f):
  c = time.time()
  _ = f()
  c2 = time.time()
  print(f"'{f.__name__}' took {c2-c}s")

@timeit
def f2():
  return sum(range(1000))
```

Output (without calling `f2`):

```
'f2' took 8.988380432128906e-05s
```

However, if attempting to call `f2`:

```
_ = f2()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

To prevent the above error, create a wrapper function inside the decorating function:

```
def timeit(f):
 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    c = time.time()
    _result = f(*args, **kwargs)
    c2 = time.time()
    print(f"'{f.__name__}' took {c2-c}s")
    return _result
 return wrapper

@timeit
def f2():
  return sum(range(1000))
```

`f2` will not be timed until it is called, triggering `wrapper`:

```
print(f2())
```

Output:

```
'f2' took 3.981590270996094e-05s
499500
```